# Raise event whenever function returns true without update loop

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Right now I do not have an update loop in my program and I would like to avoid having one for future flexibility, but I am not sure if this is possible without one.

If I have a Boolean value like: `bool Update => a == b && c != d` , is it possible to have a function get called automatically when that is true.

Alternatively, I know I can do something like this:

```
CheckUpdate() 
{ 
   if(Update) 
       *do something here* 
}
```

But I'd like the message to be sent the moment value is true, not when the update loop detects that it is true.

Comment: You could check `Update` and fire the event in a function which is called from the setters of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Comment: I thought about that too, but one issue is if the update condition changes, I'll need to create more custom setters or remove custom setters from existing properties.  Basically, I am looking to do this the most clean way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a State class that you then attach your events to using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public class State: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string a;
    private string b;
    private string c;
    private string d;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string A
    {
        get { return this.a; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.a)
            {
                this.a= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    ... so on and so forth ...
}
```

Now all you have to do is assign a handler to the property change...

```
var myState = new State();
myState += (sender,args) => 
{
    if( myState.A == myState.B && myState.C != myState.D)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

The reason I use the interface is so the object can be used in an `ObservableCollection` too if needed. This way you can manage multiple states at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        _update = () => a == b && c != d;
    }

    private Func<bool> _update;

    private string a;
    private string b;
    private string c;
    private string d;
    private string e;
    private string f;
    private string g;
    private string h;

    private void CheckUpdate()
    {
        if (_update())
        {
            /*do something here*/
        }
    }

    public string A { get { return a; } set { a = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string B { get { return b; } set { b = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string C { get { return c; } set { c = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string D { get { return d; } set { d = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string E { get { return e; } set { e = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string F { get { return f; } set { f = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string G { get { return g; } set { g = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
    public string H { get { return h; } set { h = value; CheckUpdate(); } }
}
```

It doesn't matter how many properties you have you just call `CheckUpdate()` on every update. You can then change `_update` at any time, compile-time or run-time, to suit your requirements.